# Let $G$ be a group. Consider $G\to G, z\mapsto xzx^{-1}$. Is this injective? Is it surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, inverse-function

Let $G$ be a not necessarily finite group.  For $x \in G$, consider the map $G\to G, \, z\mapsto xzx^{-1}$. Is this map injective? Is this map surjective?

I believe that the map is injective because there exists an inverse map $y\mapsto x^{-1}yx$ that will return $z$.

However, I cannot figure out if it is surjective.  My intuition says it is a bijection but I am not sure how to demonstrate that.

Comment: You have produced an inverse so...

Comment: Yes I have but I was not sure how to formalize it.  Belowe, Jose specified that for this map $g:G\to G$ 
$$\forall z \in G, f(g(z))= g(f(z)) = z$$
which demonstrates that this inverse implies it is a bijection.

Comment: It may worth noting that conjugation by a given $x \in G$ is actually an automorphism of $G$, since it is a (bijective) homomorphism: $yz \mapsto x(yz)x^{-1}=x(yx^{-1}xz)x^{-1}=(xyx^{-1})(xzx^{-1})$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a bijection. And you have defined the inverse yourself: it is the map $z\mapsto x^{-1}zx$.

Comment: Let me check the logic:  The inverse map implies it is a bijection because the inversemap, maps to the etirety of $G \to G$.  And therefore means that this map is also surjective.

Comment: No. You have a map $f\colon G\longrightarrow G$ and you wish to prove that it is a bijection. And a way of proving it is to prove that there is a map $g\colon G\longrightarrow G$ such that$$(\forall z\in G):f\bigl(g(z)\bigr)=g\bigl(f(z)\bigr).$$

Comment: Thank you!  I was struggling with the notation and this very clearly shows that it is a bijection!

Answer (score 0):

Fix any $y\in G$. Then $x^{-1}yx \mapsto x(x^{-1}yx)x^{-1}=y$. So the conjugation by $x$ is indeed surjective.